# CIFS Mount I/O Error After Large File Transfer

Tags: linux, backup, mount, samba, cifs

I have a windows network drive I access on a linux server that I mount through a mount cifs entry in /etc/fstab. I run a nightly backup of user file directories to the network drive from the linux server. However, I can only run the backup once without having to unmount and remount the network drive. The files are quite large, 80 GB or so. Each morning after the backup completes any attempt to access the mounted network file drive, gives the following message:

`ls: cannot access '/mnt/tld_k': Input/output error`

I mount the network file drive to `/mnt/tld_k`.

I mount the drive on startup through this entry in /etc/fstab. The mount works fine initially.

`//host_name/host_dir/host_sub_dir /mnt/tld_k cifs username=USER,password=PWORD,noserverino,vers=1.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0`

I've redacted the host name, user, and password for privacy.

Can anyone offer an explanation for this I/O error and a means of resolving? I do not see anything relevant in either printouts from `dmesg` or `journalctl`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the SMART info on the drive?  I put to you this is more likely a Windows side problem tjen a Linux one.

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?